# can't rendering router children

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, router, vue-router

i have a router called '/shop' and the children is /list/:id for the component named is listproduct 
but when i render on the link i go like `mylocalhost/shop/list/0812018381`  it does render ? 
 here is my routes

```
{
      path: '/shop',
      name: 'shop',
      component: () => import('./components/shop.vue'),
      children: [
        {
          path: '/list/:id',
          name: 'list',
          component: () => import('./views/detail.vue'),
        },
      ],
}
```

the component on my shop is something like this

```
<b-col>
            <div class="thiscaption my-4 p-2">

              <b-link :to="`/shop/${product._id}`">
                <h4>{{ product.productName }}</h4>
              </b-link>

              <span>
                {{
                  product.desc
                    .split(' ')
                    .slice(0, 8)
                    .join(' ')
                }}...</span
              >
              <br />

              <span>
                <b>${{ product.price }} </b>
              </span>
              <br />
              <b-button type="submit" variant="primary" class="p-2 
               my-4">add to cart</b-button>
            </div>
  </b-col>
```

i have tried to move that component list to not in children of shop, it was work, but when i use it on children shop, it doesnt render and work

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `children` property of a route, any child routes are mounted in the **parent component**. In your case it means it is mounted in `shop.vue`. To be able to mount the component in the parent component, the parent component must contain a `<router-view />` element.

Take for example the following components:

```
<!-- App.vue -->
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <span>Start App.vue</span>
    <router-view/>
    <span>End App.vue</span>
  </div>
</template>

<!-- ParentComponent.vue -->
<template>
  <div class="parent-component">
    <span>Start Parent component</span>
    <router-view/>
    <span>End Parent component</span>
  </div>
</template>

<!-- Child1.vue -->
<template>
  <div class="comp-child1">Child1.vue</div>
</template>
```

Furthermore, we have the following router:

```
// router.js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

import ParentComponent from "./components/ParentComponent";
import Child1 from "./components/Child1";
import Child2 from "./components/Child2";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        redirect: "/child1"
      },
      {
        path: "child1",
        component: Child1
      },
      {
        path: "child2",
        component: Child2
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default new VueRouter({
  routes
});
```

In this case, App.vue is the root component, because this is defined in main.js. The router says that `child1` is a child route from `/`, which renders component `ParentComponent`. Therefore we will see the start and end of app.vue. Nested in there we will see the start and end of ParentComponent. Then nested inside of that, we see Child1. Without `router-view` in either of these components, there would be no place for their children to be mounted.

[image: Edit Vue + Vuex + VueRouter template]

Comment: i did put the router view on the shop.vue, but it render on that shop.vue when i click it

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are saying. Your shop component above does not show any `router-view` element. If you put a `router-view` component in the shop component, it will obviously render the rest of the component as well.